# Can't Create Another Partition?

Tags: partition

I've been installed Kali linx on my pc ... but now i want to create another partition ... i've been searched on google they use "Gpart" ,,, but when i want to create i can't resized

this is my list drive

[image]

and this when i create but i can't

[image]

Comment: Do you try this from LiveUsb or from the installed operation system?

Comment: from installed operating system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to create a new partition from existing one, the partition table has to be rewritten. Also, when you want to rewrite a partition table, there is an effect on the existing file system. Now, as you are trying to do it from your existing installation and want to write partition table on root partition table, there is an impact on the root partition table. So, it is extremely hazardous (something like "$ rm -rf /"). These days Linux are smart enough to detect these kind of mess and it stops user upfront.

So, what you should do instead is, you should use Linux in live mode, use GParted and try repartitioning. At that time, your hard disk will not be your primary installation. So, it will allow you to do so.
But remember, you are still in risk of data loss. So, first backup the data and then try to do these type of task.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're not allowed to resize the root filesystem because it's in use. You can use Gparted to resize, but from a liveCD, not your Kali installation.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are using root partition therefore resizing won't be happening. To resize, you can try from live boot CD or from pendrive.